# Google Analytics PHP API (GAPI) returns no keywords

Tags: php, analytics, keyword, google-analytics-api, search-keywords

I'm practicing to work with GAPI and so far, I got most things to work.
At the moment I'm stuck on displaying the 5 most used keywords. All my code returns is an empty array.
I've been trying to find a solution, but so far with no success.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$ga->requestReportData(GA_PROFILE_ID, 'searchKeyword', 'pageviews', '-pageviews', null, null, null, 1, 5);
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result) {

    echo "$result - ".$result->getpageViews();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found it myself.
Appearantly, searchKeyword is for internal searches, and keyword for source searches.

Source:
Keyword: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/trafficsources#ga:keyword
searchKeyword: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/internalsearch#ga:searchKeyword

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! Was messing around with GAPI and couldn't figure out what was going on - seeing a few hundred searches from google in analytics but returning an empty array. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are sending in strings for attributes that the docs say should be arrays.

```
$ga->requestReportData(GA_PROFILE_ID, 'searchKeyword', 'pageviews', '-pageviews', null, null, null, 1, 5);
```

Try using arrays as the [documentation for GAPI](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/wiki/GAPIDocumentation) recommends:

```
$ga->requestReportData(GA_PROFILE_ID, array('searchKeyword'), array('pageviews'), array('-pageviews'), null, null, null, 1, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. I still seem to get an empty array if I dump `$ga->getResults()`.